# Developing a Simulator with Unity which needs to run on PC and Android VR glasses at the same time

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, android-unity-plugin

I'm developing a Simulator with Unity, The Sim is running on a PC and connect to the Sim and everything is working great.

The issues are that the Sim rotates 360 so i can't look and the pc screen that is in the operator station and also i want the player to be able to look around.

For that i need for the VR glasses to be connected the to what is running on the PC and run the at the same time and see the same scene, all controls are from the PC to the physical sim and back, the VR is just for that (looking around)

The only solution i could find or is to run a node.js server (for simplicity running node.js, can be any server) and getting the data from there.

I wonder if there is a better way to do that.

Sorry about not show any solution, i'm not there yet, clueless about where to start with the connection, the Simulator is running perfectly on the PC, just don't know how to connect to the VR glasses so both will see the same thing.

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement multiplayer and connect the VR as a client to the PC.
It's easy to setup and run. Your client can have VR capabilities, that the sim doesn't need.

Unity's networking (UNET) is deprecated, so I would use [Mirror](https://github.com/vis2k/Mirror). But any other networking system would also work.